# Animating a UIImageView movement and then use CGRectIntersection

Tags: ios, swift, cgrectintersectsrect

I have a UIImageView (stick) on top of my screen, and when the view appears, it animates a movement through the whole screen, until the end of it. In the middle of the screen there is a UIButton (hand) that I will press whenever the image that is going down is on top of this button.
Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {self.stick.center = CGPointMake(self.stick.center.x, 760)}, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func touchHand(sender: UIButton) {
    if !CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(stick.frame, hand.frame)){
        println("intersected")
    }

}
```

The touchHand method is when I touch the UIButton in the middle of the screen.
Problem is, it's not working!
I println'ed the stick.frame and it's not changing... I also tried animating through the YConstraint that I have and still not working because it just stays the same even though it's moving... Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624755/accessing-the-current-position-of-uiview-during-animation), so the following should help you:

```
@IBAction func touchHand(sender: UIButton) {
    let stickPresentationFrame = (stick.layer.presentationLayer() as! CALayer).frame
    if !CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(stickPresentationFrame, hand.frame)){
        println("intersected")
    }
}
```