# Subviews are not moving with parent UIView

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I'm trying to make an app based on image editing and I'm founding some problems coding a resizing by corners dragging crop area.

I have **croppingView.swift** where the crop rectangle is drawn when launched:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let imagePoint = CGPoint(x: contentView.center.x, y: contentView.center.y)

        let imageSize = CGSize(width: cropImageView.image!.size.width, height: cropImageView.image!.size.height)
        let widthScale = cropImageView.frame.width / imageSize.width
        let heightScale = cropImageView.frame.height / imageSize.height
        let scale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        let width = imageSize.width * scale
        let height = imageSize.height * scale
        let size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        let originViewFrame = CGPoint(x: imagePoint.x - width/2.0, y: imagePoint.y - height/2.0)

        let cropSize = CGSize(width: width * 0.7, height: height * 0.7)
        let cropViewFrame = CGRect(origin: originViewFrame, size: cropSize)

        cropView = ShapeView(frame: cropViewFrame)
        cropView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 224.0/255.0, green: 224.0/255.0, blue: 224.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3)
        cropView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 97.0/255.0, green: 97.0/255.0, blue: 97.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        cropView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        cropView.center = imagePoint
        self.view.addSubview(cropView)
}
```

The **ShapeView.swift** to draw the cropping area is as follows:

```
class ShapeView: UIView {

    var previousLocation = CGPoint.zero

    var topLeft = DragHandle(fillColor:UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                             strokeColor: UIColor.white)
    var topRight = DragHandle(fillColor:UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                              strokeColor: UIColor.white)
    var bottomLeft = DragHandle(fillColor:UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                                strokeColor: UIColor.white)
    var bottomRight = DragHandle(fillColor:UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 136.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
                                 strokeColor: UIColor.white)

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        superview?.addSubview(topLeft)
        superview?.addSubview(topRight)
        superview?.addSubview(bottomLeft)
        superview?.addSubview(bottomRight)

        var pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        topLeft.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        topRight.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        bottomLeft.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
        bottomRight.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleMove))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        self.updateDragHandles()
    }

    func updateDragHandles() {
        topLeft.center = self.transformedTopLeft()
        topRight.center = self.transformedTopRight()
        bottomLeft.center = self.transformedBottomLeft()
        bottomRight.center = self.transformedBottomRight()
    }

    //Gesture Methods
    @IBAction func handleMove(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.superview!)
        var center = self.center
        center.x += translation.x
        center.y += translation.y
        self.center = center
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.superview!)
        updateDragHandles()
    }

    @IBAction func handlePan(gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self)
        switch gesture.view! {
        case topLeft:
            if gesture.state == .began {
                self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
            }
            self.bounds.size.width -= translation.x
            self.bounds.size.height -= translation.y
        case topRight:
            if gesture.state == .began {
                self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
            }
            self.bounds.size.width += translation.x
            self.bounds.size.height -= translation.y

        case bottomLeft:
            if gesture.state == .began {
                self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0))
            }
            self.bounds.size.width -= translation.x
            self.bounds.size.height += translation.y
        case bottomRight:
            if gesture.state == .began {
                self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint.zero)
            }
            self.bounds.size.width += translation.x
            self.bounds.size.height += translation.y
        default:()
        }

        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
        updateDragHandles()
        if gesture.state == .ended {
            self.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5))
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm adding one circle in each corner of the rectangle. These circles are used to resize the cropping area by dragging. Here the key is the `updateDragHandles()`function which updates the positions of all other circle keeping them on the corners.

So when launching the cropping area appears like:

[image]

And when user moves for example the bottom-right corner by dragging everything is working fine:

[image]

Now the problem is when I click on the portrait button to change cropping area orientation. With the next code into **croppingView.swift** the grey rectangle correctly changes the size but the circles remain on the their position:

```
@IBAction func portButton(_ sender: Any) {
        portButton.tintColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        landButton.tintColor = UIColor.systemGray
        isPortait = 1
        let inWidth = cropView.frame.size.width
        let inHeight = cropView.frame.size.height
        if inWidth > inHeight {
            let scaleW = cropView.frame.size.height / cropView.frame.size.width
            let scaleH = cropView.frame.size.width / cropView.frame.size.height
            let fixPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            cropView.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: fixPoint)
            cropView.transform = cropView.transform.scaledBy(x: scaleW, y: scaleH)
            let vc = ShapeView()
            vc.updateDragHandles()
        }
    }
```

It's like updateDragHandles is not working from this ViewController...

[image]

Probably it's a basic mistake but I can't find out the solution.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

**DragHandle.swift**

```
let diameter:CGFloat = 30

import UIKit

class DragHandle: UIView {

  var fillColor = UIColor.darkGray
  var strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray
  var strokeWidth: CGFloat = 1.0

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Use init(fillColor:, strokeColor:)")
  }

  init(fillColor: UIColor, strokeColor: UIColor, strokeWidth width: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: diameter, height: diameter))
    self.fillColor = fillColor
    self.strokeColor = strokeColor
    self.strokeWidth = width
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
    {
        super.draw(rect)
        let handlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect.insetBy(dx: 10 + strokeWidth, dy: 10 + strokeWidth))
        fillColor.setFill()
        handlePath.fill()
        strokeColor.setStroke()
        handlePath.lineWidth = strokeWidth
        handlePath.stroke()
    }
}
```

**UIViewExtensions.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func offsetPointToParentCoordinates(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
      return CGPoint(x: point.x + self.center.x, y: point.y + self.center.y)
    }

    func pointInViewCenterTerms(point:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
      return CGPoint(x: point.x - self.center.x, y: point.y - self.center.y)
    }

    func pointInTransformedView(point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
      let offsetItem = self.pointInViewCenterTerms(point: point)
      let updatedItem = offsetItem.applying(self.transform)
      let finalItem = self.offsetPointToParentCoordinates(point: updatedItem)
      return finalItem
    }

    func originalFrame() -> CGRect {
      let currentTransform = self.transform
      self.transform = .identity
      let originalFrame = self.frame
      self.transform = currentTransform
      return originalFrame
    }

    func transformedTopLeft() -> CGPoint {
      let frame = self.originalFrame()
      let point = frame.origin
      return self.pointInTransformedView(point: point)
    }

    func transformedTopRight() -> CGPoint {
      let frame = self.originalFrame()
      var point = frame.origin
      point.x += frame.size.width
      return self.pointInTransformedView(point: point)
    }

    func transformedBottomRight() -> CGPoint {
      let frame = self.originalFrame()
      var point = frame.origin
      point.x += frame.size.width
      point.y += frame.size.height
      return self.pointInTransformedView(point: point)
    }

    func transformedBottomLeft() -> CGPoint {
      let frame = self.originalFrame()
      var point = frame.origin
      point.y += frame.size.height
      return self.pointInTransformedView(point: point)
    }

    func setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint) {
      var newPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, y: self.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y)
      var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width * self.layer.anchorPoint.x, y: self.bounds.size.height * self.layer.anchorPoint.y)

      newPoint = newPoint.applying(self.transform)
      oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(self.transform)

      var position = self.layer.position
      position.x -= oldPoint.x
      position.x += newPoint.x
      position.y -= oldPoint.y
      position.y += newPoint.y

      self.layer.position = position
      self.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame especially the warning part. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624755/accessing-the-current-position-of-uiview-during-animation might help, but not sure with transformations

Comment: What does the `DragHandle` class look like?  Is their position setup in their own `didMoveToSuperview()`?

Comment: Hi @clawesome thank you for your answer. I've edited my question adding the DragHandle class.

Comment: I think what we really need to see is what happens in the transform methods in `updateDragHandles()`

Comment: Sure @clawesome! I've added the extensions class that I'm using into `updateDragHandles()`

Comment: In `func originalFrame()` that is essentially removing all the transforms to get the original frame right?  And `updateDragHandles()` uses that original frame to update their locations, so when your button is pressed you add a transform to change it from landscape/portrait but when the drag handles are updated after that, they are done so by the original frames position which is calculated by removing the transform for the new orientation.